# Ionics Rewrite Filter setup on IIS 5.1

Tags: windows-xp, rewrite, iis, zend-framework

I'm trying to configure IIRF 2 on IIS 5.1 running on XP Pro, so that I can run the Zend Framework.

I've managed to get the filter running on a second website that I setup using one the IIS admin scripts.

When I goto iirfStatus I get this:

[image]

The problem is the .ini path for the site is pointing to c:\windows\system32\Irif.ini rather than the site root. If I try creating an IIS application under IIS->Website Properties->Home Directory then iirfStatus stops working entirely.

Any ideas how I can set the ini path correctly, or will I only be able to get away with this on a proper server edition of IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Place a file called iirf.ini with the following contents in the application home directory.

```
RewriteEngine ON
StatusUrl /iirfStatus
```

The reason /iirfStatus seems to stop working when you add a new application is because IIRF is unable to load the iirf.ini file which must contain at least the directives above.